# PHP functions for everything - Advice Needed

Tags: php

I have a bad feeling about this, even though everything works fine (for me at least ). on my page I'm using functions for pretty much everything. In detail, for login page I created a function (functions.php).

```
  function  phpLogin() {
    echo '<form action="process.php" method="POST">';
    echo '<input type="text" name="username" />';
    echo '<input type="password" name="password"/>';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"/>';
    }
```

and I'm calling this function via `isset(GET['login']){phpLogin();}` in my main page.

Is it okey to do things like this in php or It is forbidden/very bad practice.

I forgot to mention this:- I chose this over iframes/includes. Because 
there is a navigation pane on left of my page which is static and the the actions/process should be visible on the right pane. and the above showed function is just an example.
thank you

Comment: Parsing plain HTML with PHP is just an overkill. You can simply do it with HTML.

Comment: `echo '<form action="process.php" method="POST">';` It's a bad practice!

Comment: Functions are meant for *reusable* actions. Wrapping everything in a function, including the HTML, is unnecessary and will make your code a mess moving forward. Not to mention it clutters up the global namespace.

Comment: I chose this over <iframe> because i need to show multiple things on main page.

Comment: Yes this is a bad practice. Use the built-in php templating or templating engine like twig.

Answer (score 2):

Making function for everything is not necessarily a bad thing. If your website is too big and have huge amount of HTML codes then creating and **reusing** functions will be better.

On the other hand if your website is small and you are using this Login function only once in your program then you might be better if you directly put this code in your template instead of making the function.

My recommendation is, if you are starting PHP, then try using a template engine like [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/). It separates the HTML from PHP and give you much precise and better way to work for your programs.